# Randomly and evenly assign students from large list to teachers from small list

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, random

If I have a worksheet of students #120 and a worksheet of teachers #40.

How can I assign say three students per teacher - could I use the =RAND function but allow for duplicates someway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use =RAND() - for sorting your list of students. Then assign in sets of three to the teachers.

Comment: Thank you, could you tell me how I could do the assigning part?